# How prevent update automatically in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa

I have a JPA entity as follow:

```
@Entity
@DynamicUpdate
@TypeDef(name = "json_binary", typeClass = JsonBinaryType::class)
public class Workflow {
   private Long id;
   private String name;

   @Type(type = "json_binary")
   @Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb")
   private List<AccessModel> users;
}

public class AccessModle {
   private String name;
   private Int permission;
}
```

And the repository:

```
@Repository
public interface WorkflowRepository extends JpaRepository<Workflow, Long> {}
```

Now when I **just** want to find a `workflow`(repository.findById(1)), The hibernate log is as follow:

```
Hibernate: select workflow0_.id as id1_12_0_, workflow0_.name as name2_12_0_, 
           workflow0_.users as users3_12_0_ where workflow0_.id=?
Hibernate: update workflow set users=? where id=?
```

I didn't modify `users`, But Hibernate set it. How can I prevent automatically update entity?

**Update:**

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class WorkflowServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private WorkflowRepository repository;

    public Workflow find(Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the service method which calls `repository.findById(1)`?

Comment: Define equals and hashcode in `AccessModle` so that jpa can verify fields not updated

Comment: Can you show us your controller or Service impl which has the method call?

Comment: It shouldn't issue update at all with the code you have shown us. Who is calling `workflowService. find` and what they are doing with the result and does that method have `@Transactional` too?

Answer (score 2):

You have added `@Transactional` at service level so, it will be applicable for each method present in the service class. You need to add  `@Transactional(readOnly = true)` on your `find(Long id)` method. It will solve your problem.

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class WorkflowServiceImpl {

    @Autowired
    private WorkflowRepository repository;

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public Workflow find(Long id) {
        return repository.findById(id);
    }
}
```

It is best practice to add the `@Transactional` on required methods only instead at the class level.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the following properties (`insertable = false, updatable = false`) along with the definition for `@Column` --

`@Column(columnDefinition = "jsonb", insertable = false, updatable = false)`

This will prevent from inserting or updating the value for the `users`